# Pretty formatting xml file in Python using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to add a vhost entry to tomcat server.xml using python lxml

```
import io
from lxml import etree

newdoc = etree.fromstring('<Host name="getrailo.com" appBase="webapps"><Context path=""    docBase="/var/sites/getrailo.org" /><Alias>www.getrailo.org</Alias><Alias>my.getrailo.org</Alias></Host>')
doc = etree.parse('/root/server.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
for node1 in root.iter('Service'):
        for node2 in node1.iter('Engine'):
                node2.append(newdoc)
doc.write('/root/server.xml')
```

The problem is that it is removing the
    `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`

line on top of the file from the output and the vhost entry is all in one line .How can I add the xml element in a pretty way like

```
<Host name="getrailo.org" appBase="webapps">
         <Context path="" docBase="/var/sites/getrailo.org" />
         <Alias>www.getrailo.org</Alias>
         <Alias>my.getrailo.org</Alias>
</Host>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse existing file with `remove_blank_text` so that it's clean and with no extra spaces that I think is a problem in this case

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
newdoc = etree.fromstring('/root/server.xml' parser=parser)
```

Then you're safe to write it back to disk with `pretty_print` and `xml_declaration` set in `doc.write()`

```
doc.write('/root/server.xml',  
          xml_declaration=True, 
          encoding='utf-8', 
          pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Could you explain what you do and how it will fix the issue? While it may fix the issue, code-only answer is not recommended since it may confuse the OP and future readers.

Comment: This fixed the xml declaration on top. But I am still seeing the vhost entry cluttered and no new line is there at the end of it . I even tried passing the \n entry in the string which is ignored

Comment: Well, it's not too complicated code to read for a Python programmer, to understand what it's doing all you need is to look into the doc for doc.write method, I could paste a snipped of the doc here but I thought it's more useful for a person asking a question to dig a little bit